# In C++ and GCC on Linux, is it possible to allocate memory to your swap space instead of your RAM?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-usage, gcc

I have a large hash, around 6 gigabytes that I load into memory. On my current laptop that I develop from, it really does a number on my system, causing massive amounts of lag while I try to go about other things, say for example, debugging or browsing stack overflow. This would not be an issue if I could simply store the hash exclusively on my swap space, while leaving the primary memory available for more important programs.

Is this sort of thing at all possible, insofar as GCC is concerned? Are there memory managers which can do this sort of thing? And if not, what are my best options that do not require me to set up a PostgreSQL server?

I really only need this while I am debugging. Eventually the program will sit on a server where this will not be necessary.

Comment: Why not use a sqlite database for your hash table?

Comment: It might help if you map it instead of reading it in, but that depends on access-patterns.

Comment: @DocBrown I will do that. I did not realize that sqlite was created for this purpose.

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you be a bit more specific? When I hear map, I think of the template class, which I do not think would be right, given that Maps get less efficient at lookups as the contents scale up.

Comment: Map the data into the addree space, instead of reading it in. Thus, only what you access is actually read. Ryan elaborated below.

Comment: wtf is swap space

Comment: @Asadefa Linux divides its physical RAM (random access memory) into chucks of memory called pages. Swapping is the process whereby a page of memory is copied to the preconfigured space on the hard disk, called swap space, to free up that page of memory. The combined sizes of the physical memory and the swap space is the amount of virtual memory available.

Comment: @Akiva Hmmm. Uh. Ok thanks I guess I understand now

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple (at least conceptually), all that you need is `mmap()` a file and then just write your own `malloc()` or override the `new` operator so that they allocate memory from the mmap-ed region.

But do note that this will still use RAM, all that this really does is move your memory usage from process virtual memory to filesystem cache memory. There are flags you can pass to `mmap()` to map the files directly without cache, but this means that every update to these memory involves synchronous write and they can be really slow.

Alternatively, just use sqlite. sqlite already implements all these stuffs for you.

---

With that said, I think you have an XY problem. I think what you're really needing here is to reduce the IO priority of your process. In Linux, you can do this using `nice` and `ionice`.